# CSS: Selecting table's <td> without the <td>s of nested tables

Tags: css

How do you select the *td* elemennts of a table, without the *td*'s of the nested tables ?
 
I thought of the following selector: `table > tbody > tr > td` to make sure I don't have the *td* elements of the nested tables, but I guess there is a better way ?

Comment: a nested table, is a table inside a table.
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/tables/nestingtables.html

Comment: Can you make your question a little bit more clear?, why dont you use  id's or classes to specify the `td` ?

Comment: What's wrong with the selector you've entered?

Comment: What is not clear. I specifically asked how to select TD elements, without the TDs of nested TABLEs. Maybe it's my clumsy English?

Comment: As Kong said, your selector already does exactly that.

Comment: The OP wants to select this level...  `table > tbody > tr > td`     NOT `table > tbody > tr > td > table > tr td`.   Only the `td` contained in the top most table.

Comment: Tough crowd today... what's with everyone downvoting this guy's question?  It's very clear what he wants.   Why all the hate?

Comment: Indeed my selector does the job fine, but I thought it was possible to make a shorter selector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you have this?

```html
<table id="outer">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table id="anotherTable">
            ...
            </table>
         <td>
      <tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And you want to only select td's in the root table.

```css
#outer>tbody>tr>td
```

Just like you entered in your question (direct child selectors).

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way is to add an id or class to that outermost table, an then use that in your selector:

```css
table#id > tbody > tr > td
```

Comment: A semi-related question:  If you don't explicitly put a <tbody> tag in your HTML, will one always be created by the browser anyway?  And should a CSS rule like the one you have in your answer always include "> tbody >" ?

Comment: @DerWolf I can't really speak for _every_ browser, but it does seem to happen in at least some. I think you'd always want to add it, or potentially have two selectors (one with, one without) just to be absolutely certain that some other browser isn't going to throw you for a loop.

Though to be honest, in a real use case I might even just recommend setting styles just with a `td` selector, and then manually resetting them with a `table table td` selector if you need something different in nested tables, since presumably the nested table is within a `td` itself and would inherit anyways

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible. What you might do is overwrite any unwanted styles to the nested table cells. So if you apply a red background to a cell, and that cell has nested cells, you need to overwrite the nested cells with the original background color.